# Joining lines in MapInfo that won't be split by disaggregate?

Tags: mapinfo, attribute-joins, line

I have just run a disaggregation a .tab containing just lines and found I have a few with duplicate IDs. However when I zoom in these lines appear to be connected. Is there any way to join these together so they won't be split up next time it is disaggregated?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: About that lines, are they multisection lines ?

Answer (score 1):

Alan,
You need to make sure that the start or end point of the two lines do match up. If there is just a very small difference between these two points, MapInfo Pro will not see them as the same point and will not combine the two lines into a pline with a single segment, but into a pline with multiple segments.

To make sure they match up:

- Make the layer editable
- Select one of the objects
- Turn on Reshape
- Turn on Snap using the S-key
- Select the end point closest to the other object
- Drag the end point a bit away from the other object and then back to the other object.
- Make sure that it snaps

Now you should be able to combine the two objects into a pline with a single segment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, turns out it was an error on my part. When zoomed in very far there were VERY small lines coming off at the area the two lines joined so there were infact three. Once this was deleted and the two remaining lines joined they would no longer be split up.